# Stop NSThread on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsthread

I have function call loop, but I want call it if my view appears, and not call it when the view disappears.

Loop Function :

```
-(void)updateArray
   {

    while (1)
    {
        NSLog(@"IN LOOP");
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];
        if([FileSizeArray count] >0 || [FileCurrentSizeArray count] >0)
        {
            [FileSizeArray removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(1, FileSizeArray.count-1)];
            [FileCurrentSizeArray removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(1, FileSizeArray.count-1)];
        }
        [FileNameArray removeAllObjects];
        [UserNameArray removeAllObjects];
        ...
}
```

And in `ViewWillAppear()`

```
timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 2.0
                                              target: self
                                              selector:@selector(updateArray:)
                                              userInfo: nil repeats:NO];
```

And in `DidDisAppear()`

```
[timer invalidate];
timer = nil;
```

But it not working, it still call and my app has crash.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add the error message you received when the app crashed and on which line it crashed? Also `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval...` schedules the timer on current thread (which is the main one, since it's called from `viewWillAppear`), and you shouldn't call `[NSThread sleep...]` on main thread.

Comment: because your method doesn't have any paramters and though you are passing it, just change method name in timer to (updateArray) it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that what you really want to do is use [Key-Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) to receive a callback when `FileSizeArray` and `FileCurrentSizeArray` change.

In `ViewDidAppear`:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"FileSizeArray.count" options: 0 context: nil];
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"FileCurrentSizeArray.count" options: 0 context: nil];
```

Callback:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

   if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"FileSizeArray.count"]) {   
      //do something
   } else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"FileCurrentSizeArray.count"]) {
      //do something
   }

}
```

remember to unregister:

```
[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"FileSizeArray"];
[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"FileCurrentSizeArray"];
```

Comment: Thanks but It's not work, I want to stop NSThread when view disappear.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that `count` is not a KVO-compliant property.

Answer (score 0):

`[NSThread exit];` or `[NSThread performSelector:@selector(exit) onThread:thread withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];`