# How to stop call loop function in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsthread

I want to stop calling loop function when View disapear. How can i do that? This is my code:

```
    -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateArray)  withObject:nil];

}
```

And :

```
    -(void)updateArray
{

while (1)
{
    NSLog(@"IN LOOP");
   [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];
....}
```

updateArray is callled usually when this View disappear. I want to stop call updateArray function

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you cleared  with your question?

Comment: How is this different from your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438987/stop-nsthread-on-ios ?

Comment: Well ... u can use `break;` to stop any loop.

Comment: if use break it won't call again when view appear.

Answer (score 2):

Make an `BOOL` iVar or property

```
BOOL loopShouldRun;
```

in viewWillAppear set it to `YES`.

then use this code

```
-(void)updateArray
{
  while (loopShouldRun)
    {
      NSLog(@"IN LOOP");
      [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];
....}
}
```

and in viewWillDisappear set it to NO.

But as @Michael Deuterman mentioned in the comments there could be a problem when the view disappears before the sleepTimer fires.

So heres is another solution with a NSTimer.

- create a `NSTimer` iVar/@property:  `@property (strong) NSTimer *timer;`
- in `viewWillAppear` create the timer:

  `timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:2.0 invocation:@selector(updateArray) repeats:Yes]`
- in `viewWillDiappear` invalidate the timer:

  `if ([self.timer isValid]) {
    [self.timer invalidate]
  }`

your `updateArray` should look now like this:

```
-(void)updateArray {
  NSLog(@"in loop");
}
```

Comment: This isn't the optimal answer. The problem with this @Pfitz, is that the view may be disappeared and released before the long sleep time in "`sleepForTimeInterval: 2.0`" returns.

Comment: timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:2.0 invocation:@selector(updateArray) repeats:Yes] it error. It don't work

Answer (score 0):

```
while (1)
{
    NSLog(@"IN LOOP");
   [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];
}
```

while(1) will be true forever. To stop it, you need to have a condition that will stop the loop from happening.

For example,

```
while (1)
{
    NSLog(@"IN LOOP");
   [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];
   if(something happens)
    break;
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: or while(!(something happens)){...}

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple logic...just take one flag variable and update the value of that flag varibale when your viewdisapper then

```
 - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

above method method will call just before view disappear

`viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated`

above method is also there. that will be called just after your view did disappeared

so you can change your flag variable's value in one of above method.then according your flag variable value  just put  `break` in your while loop and your loop will broke
.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSThread` instead of `performSelector`

```
NSThread *myThread; // preferable to declare in class category in .m file or in .h file
```

In **viewWillAppear**

```
myThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updateArray) object:nil];
[myThread start];
```

In **viewWillDisappear**

```
[myThread cancel]; // This will stop the thread and method will get stopped from execution
myThread = nil; // Release and nil object as we are re-initializing in viewWillAppear
```

For more details refer this : [NSThread Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Please let me know is this the way you required?